# How to Read/Write CSV file dynamically?

Tags: java, csv

I have to create a csv file dynamically, i created it dynamically ....help please with full code

```
public class CSV {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("d:/test.csv"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("id");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("Name");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append('\n');

        sb.append("1");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("Akash");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append('\n');

        pw.write(sb.toString());
        pw.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're nearly done. I created [a running variation of your code](https://ideone.com/gecW51) that does its output to stdout instead of a file:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
```

Try to get the difference as to understand your problem.